# Elasticsearch or Mongodb

Tags: database, mongodb, elasticsearch, database-design

we are using elasticsearch and our use case allows our clients to create many indexes to import their one to many data. One index is created for each one to many field. The problem comes that this indexes can be anywhere from 10kb to 10gb, but manly the indexes are arround 1mb-500mb.
My question is , did we made right choice with elasticsaerch or maybe a better data storage can be MongoDB.
We allow clients to create search on each field but mainly all searches are if field is equal, not equal, larger, smaller than. In some cases we use LIKE operator on text fields.

Thanks.

Comment: If you don't have fulltext search and you don't need semantic searching using ES it might be over kill and cost you more.

Comment: Is it a problem that my cluster that have 1 master and 4 data nodes can reach max number of indexes with this many small indexes ?

Comment: It can be problem if your indices are small and the fact how ES stores indices.

Comment: Thanks, i guess i will try out mongoDB to see it's performance